# Change style based on useState variable in React

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-hooks, use-ref

I want to animate a search icon on click in React. I am using useRef hook to get the element and I pass some custom style to the component.

```
const [searchBar, setSearchBar ] = useState(false);
const searchIcon = useRef();
const searchIconStyle = {
    transition: 'rotate .3s ease', // smooth transition
    rotate: searchBar? "360deg" : "0",
}

function handleSearchClick(e) {
    setSearchBar(prevState => !prevState);
}
```

So, the code from above is working first time when I click, but it doesn't afterwards. The search icon is a FontAwesome component

```
 {searchBar && <input type="search" placeholder="Search product..."/>}
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faMagnifyingGlass} className="search-icon"
            onClick={handleSearchClick} ref={searchIcon} style={searchIconStyle}/>
```

How can I animate the icon on each click (depending on the change of **searchBar** variable?)

Comment: you get **FontAwesomeIcon**  from which library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're not setting the rotate property properly.

**just change  :**

```
rotate: searchBar? "360deg" : "0",
```

**to  :**

```
 rotate: searchBar? "360deg" : "0deg",
```

this is a demo in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/combobox-material-demo-forked-vywosl?file=/demo.js) ( I used a button instead of FontAwesomeIcon  cause you didn't tell which library you are using)

Answer (score 0):

I like use classnames. Example for you:

```
className={classNames(
  { 'basicStyle': true},
  { 'withoutAnimation': !searchBar },
  { 'withAnimation': searchBar },
)}
```